# How to write "(event, state) -> state" function on Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to write fold function like "(event, state) -> state". How I can write it if no any pattern-matching and immutable in Java?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for ***Functional Programming*** in Java.

Lambda Expressions, a new language feature in JAVA 8, has been introduced in this release. They enable you to treat functionality as a method argument, or code as data. Lambda expressions let you express instances of single-method interfaces (referred to as functional interfaces) more compactly.

Learn more here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach5

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways Java 8+ allows you to do this is with `BiFunction`.  For example:

```
public BiFunction<Event, State, State> biFunctionMethod(){
    return (event, state) -> {
        Object obj = doSomethingWithEventAndOldState(event, state);
        return new State(obj);  // not changing the old state
    };
}
```

You then call this as follows:

```
public void run(){
    State newState = biFunctionMethod().apply(event, state);
}
```